# groovy unable to resolve class hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry

Tags: java, svn, groovy, jenkins

I am trying to get the change list from SVN using groovy script on Jenkins.
This is what I am working with:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*
import hudson.scm.*
import hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry

def build = Thread.currentThread()?.executable

def thr = Thread.currentThread()

def envVarsMap = build.parent.builds[0].properties.get("envVars")

// get ChangesSets with all changed items
def changeSet= build.getChangeSet()
List<LogEntry> items = changeSet.getItems()

def affectedFiles = items.collect { it.paths }
def fileNames = affectedFiles.flatten()

new File(envVarsMap["WORKSPACE"],'ChangesSets.txt').withWriter { out ->
fileNames.each {
  out.println it.path
}
}
```

But on running syntax check on Jankins I get this error:

```
startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry
@ line 4, column 1.
 import hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry
 ^

1 error
```

I am new to groovy and any pointers will be very helpful.

Groovy version:   2.3.7
JDK:     java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Windows 64 Bit OS

EDIT:

I found this file under subversion-plugin. 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/scm/SubversionChangeLogSet.java

In Jenkins install this is located under:
C:\Jenkins\plugins\subversion\WEB-INF\lib\classes.jar\hudson\scm\SubversionChangeLogSet.class

Basically under C:\Jenkins\plugins\subversion\WEB-INF\lib in classes.jar file.

Any pointers how to get access to that. I think I am close to solution but not close enough.

Comment: does `List<SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry>` instead of the import work?

Comment: Where did u try this script ? it works ok for jenkins script console.